# Tensors which are symmetric and antisymmetric in overlapping groups

Tags: tensors

Say I have the following tensor $T_{abc}$ such that
$$
T_{(a[b)c]}
$$
Ergo, it is symmetric in indices $a$ and $b$ and antisymmetric in $b$ and $c$.

Keeping in mind the various properties that (anti-)symmetry entails such as switching and the like, can $a$ and $c$ actually be switched around?

I am trying to show that tensors having such a property vanish, but I get stuck when I get $T_{bac}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $T$ is symmetric in $a, b$ and skew in $b, c$, or that the indicated symmetrization of $T$ is $0$? In the latter case, this is a priori ambiguous and the indicated symmetrization and antisymmetrization operations do not commute. In either case, I would avoid overlapping $(\cdots)$ and $[\cdots]$ like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $T_{abc} = T_{bac} = -T_{bca} = -T_{cba} = T_{cab} = T_{acb} = -T_{abc}$, so $T_{abc} = 0$.